# Can other Infinity Stones be melted into liquid?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, infinity-stones

For example, we have seen in MCU that the Reality Stone was melted into a red liquid (called the Aether).

Is this possible with other Stones as well?

Comment: Aether wasn't melted. It was the only Infinity Stone which existed in liquid form.

Comment: @UmbrellaCorporation But it was in solid form as well right? Should I edit the question like "Can phase of other infinity stones be changed, say from solid to liquid?"

Comment: @UmbrellaCorporation https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Reality_Stone this link says that reality stone was melted by dark elves to harness its power. Is it wrong?

Comment: Yeah, that's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t think there is any explicit answer to this but I’m going to go out on a limb and say no, ***not by themselves*** anyway. We’ve never seen any of the others become a different form on their own.

Each Infinity Stone controls an essential aspect of existence and we’ve seen they act differently because of it. The Soul Stone holds a special place amongst the Infinity Stones demanding a sacrifice. The Power Stone holds immense power so only powerful beings may use it, anyone else is just over powered and destroyed as we see in *Guardians of the Galaxy*.

The Reality Stone changes what people perceive as, well, reality. It can turn Drax into cubes or stretch out Mantis. It can turn into the Aether, a liquid, because it is changing its own reality.

However, they could probably become liquid if the wielder of the full Infinity Gauntlet were to make them all liquid. After all if it can destroy them (reduce them to atoms), turning them to liquid should be well within its capabilities.

> **NATASHA ROMANONFF:** Where are the Stones?
>
> **THANOS:** Gone. Reduced to atoms.
>
> **BRUCE BANNER:** You used them two days ago!
>
> **THANOS:** I used the stones to destroy the stones. It nearly killed me. But the work is done. It always will be. I am... inevitable.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

Comment: Hmm with infinity gauntlet, there is always this possibility as you mentioned.

Comment: Hasn't it happened that someone changed the phase of stones? Something Like reality stone was melted by dark elves, has anyone tried doing that with other stones?

Comment: @user1170874 The MCU Wiki that mentions the Reality Stone being liquefied doesn't offer any evidence to back it up. And even if it did they would have been harnessing the power of the Stone itself to make it liquid which makes sense. I'm not aware of anyone trying the same with the others.